# Difference between *pointervar and (*pointervar)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

On [this page](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/linked-list/) I've found the following code:

```
//insert a new node in front of the list
void push(struct Node** head, int node_data)
{
   /* 1. create and allocate node */
   struct Node* newNode = new Node;
 
   /* 2. assign data to node */
   newNode->data = node_data;
 
   /* 3. set next of new node as head */
   newNode->next = (*head);
 
   /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
   (*head) = newNode;
}
```

Now I'd like to know why in the third line `*head` is in brackets?
What is the difference between `*head` and `(*head)` ?

Comment: The brackets around `*head` are not needed. You can remove the brackets. It would have the effect as with brackets.

Comment: I usually add *unnecessary* parens around expressions when I'm mixing bitwise operators, arithmetic operators, and logical operators.  Or if I have multiple logical subexpressions, I often put redundant parens around non-leaf subexpressions.  I do so as a way that (I believe) helps legibility, because not everyone has the operator precedence order memorized.  Does `a && b || c` mean `(a && b) || c` or `a && (b || c)`? With the parens, no need to puzzle over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between `*head` and `(*head)` ?

The brackets around `*head` are not needed. You can remove the brackets. It would have the effect as with brackets.

Usually, we explicitly put brackets around an expression, to circumvent/**override operator precedence rules**.

But ***in your example***, **there is no difference with or without brackets** .

---

An example where the parenthesis are needed is shown below:

```
struct C
{
    void f(int);
};

int main() {
    auto ptr = &C::f;
    C c;
    (c.*ptr)(5); //PARENTHESIS NEEDED HERE ; this compiles
   // c.*ptr(5);   //this won't compile! because of operator precedence rules   
}
```